# TestNG failFast stops Listener

Tags: java, gradle, testng, build.gradle, listener

I have failFast enabled in my `build.gradle`.
I implemented an `ITestListener` to react on failing Tests, and implemented it within my *Test.xml*. If I disable `failFast`, the `onTestFailure` method of my listener is executed without any problems (if a Test fails, of course). But when it is enabled, my code inside the method is randomly aborted. No Errors occure or at least are not displayed.
My guess is that failFast terminates the entire process without waiting to see if there is any code left to execute. Is there a workaround? Maybe running the listener async?

Comment: Since failFast would make the build fail when the first failed test is encountered, Could please explain why you have both failFast and onTestFailure at the same time. Or please provide details on what you are doing inside the onTestFailure.

Comment: I want to react to failed tests and send them to a Telegram channel to be able to react quickly if necessary. This works quite well so far. Only if failFast is activated none of my listeners reacts as desired. But since there are a lot of tests running on the CI, it doesn't make sense to turn failFast off.